# Regex to validate multiple domain names

Tags: regex

I'm trying to use regex (from Javascript) to validate a list of domain names. For example, if the user enters:

```
facebook.com
stackoverflow.com
apple.com
```

... the regex should validate OK. However,

```
facebook.com
clearlynotadomainname
apple.com
```

... should fail validation.

I'm using this the regex expression:

`^([a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$`

which works fine for the first line of text, but as soon as the user enters the first CR/LF the expression fails. Is it possible to get regex to iterate through, or otherwise parse, all lines in a string?

Comment: question is very unclear..ur valid-invalid examples are not sufficient nd r ambiguous

Comment: In the first example, all three lines are valid domain names. In the second example, lines 1 and 3 are valid domains, whilst the 2nd line is not a domain name. The regex expression catches this for a single line, but not for multiple lines. Is this any clearer?

Comment: have you tried using the modifier g or m? ^ is used to define start of a string and $ for the end of string...

Comment: Daan's solution below is working for me - thanks @ChaosClown anyway! Got to love people who complain about clarity whilst misspelling "your" and "are" ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply split the string on newlines? Assuming you want to ignore empty lines:

```
function testString(str) {
  var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}(\n|$)/
  var split = str.split('\n')

  for(var i = 0; i < split.length; ++i) {
    if(split[i] != ''&& !regex.test(split[i]))
      return false
  }

  return true
}

testString('facebook.com\nstackoverflow.com\napple.com')
=> true
testString('facebook.com\nclearlynotadomainname\napple.com')
=> false
```

Comment: Perfect - embarrassed I didn't think of that myself :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To validate the [,;] domains(only) you can use :

```
^\s*(?:(?:\w+(?:-+\w+)*\.)+[a-z]+)\s*(?:[;,]\s*(?:(?:\w+(?:-+\w+)*\.)+[a-z]+)\s*)*$
```

Tested on different cases.